# Why is my code in vue.config.js not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass-loader

### **vue.config.js isn't running**

I'm working on Vue project and I created it with vue-cli. I wrote this code inside vue.config.js to not `@import` variables.scss and mixins.scss **manually** to all my components.

```
module.exports = {
 css: {
  loaderOptions: {
   sass: {
    additionalData: `
      @import "@/assets/styles/_variables.scss";
      @import "@/assets/styles/_mixins.scss";
      `,
   },
  },
 },
}
```

- ***vue.config.js is [in the root of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpmpx.png) same as package.json.***(Click  hyperlink to see the picture)
- Inside my src folder: `src/assets/styles/_variable.scss`

But, Vue doesn't read the code in vue.config.js

**Here is my dependencies and devDependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.21.0",
  "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
  "bootstrap-vue": "^2.20.1",
  "core-js": "^3.6.5",
  "moment": "^2.29.1",
  "vue": "^2.6.12",
  "vue-router": "^3.4.9",
  "vuelidate": "^0.7.6",
  "vuex": "^3.6.0"
},
 "devDependencies": {
   "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
   "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
   "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
   "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
   "eslint": "^6.7.2",
   "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
   "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
   "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
   "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
```

When I run the `npm run serve`, I get the following error

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable: "$secondary-color".
    on line 50 of src/components/BlogItem.vue
   >>       color: $secondary-color;
```

**Do I need to install some packages?**
**Or should I change the version of *sass-loader*?**

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work". I have the same "unknown" issue you have, but my works just right.

Comment: @CristianoSoleti  I've tried different ways like changing path, sass to scss. Then, I saw Vue also doesn't read `devServer: { proxy : { //some code }}` object inside vue.config. Therefore, I decided "unknown" is the problem. If it works right in your code, what causes the issue ?

Comment: You are still not answering the "is not working" question. What does it mean to you? Can we have any stack trace or screenshot? The easiest thing you can do to test is changing the dev server port.

Comment: @CristianoSoleti I mean Vue doesn't read the code. As if, it doesn't see vue.config file. I don't know how to explain this with other words. I created the vue.config file and added [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQSTs.png)  codes. All I do is this.

Comment: *unknown* has nothing to do with your problem, this is normal and how it is for everyone.  Your `additionalData` syntax looks ok but your question is confusing.  You said:  "to **not** @import"?  So you don't want to import?

Comment: @Dan no no. to not import scss files **manually** to all my components. If this code works, it will automatically add scss files to all components and pages. I just want to know why my code isn't running although it is true

Comment: PLEASE LOOK AT THE CODES BY CLICKING THE HYPERLINKS.
This is [whole code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqzAw.png) in vue.config.js. My `devServer: {}` isn't running as well, therefore I must **manually** add my proxy to all `get()` responses [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH8uQ.png). When I delete the proxy and only write `/api/v1/blogs`, code doesn't run.

Comment: With your current value of `additionalData`, you should see this error upon running the `serve`/`build` npm script: `SassError: semicolons aren't allowed in the indented syntax.`.

Comment: To troubleshoot whether `vue.config.js` is actually being read, verify that the `serve`/`build` npm scripts contain `vue-cli-service`. In `vue.config.js`, add this line at the very beginning before `module.exports`: `throw new Error('just a test')`, and then run the `serve`/`build` script again to check for the error in your terminal.

Comment: @tony19 Yes, my script contains `serve` and `build`. `"scripts": "serve": "vue-cli-service serve", "build": "vue-cli-service build", "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"},`

When I wrote `throw new Error('just a test')`, it said unreachable code to `module.exports`. I guess this is normal. And after `npm run serve` it gave [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srpqB.png) in terminal

Comment: I SOLVED `devServer:{}` ERROR BY ADDING `/` AFTER `^` IN PROXY. BUT I CANNOT SOLVE TO IMPORT MY `.scss` FILES AUTOMATICALLY WITH `module.exports`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The thing was I forgot to write `<style lang="scss">` in App.vue file. Maybe It would help you.

Comment: This was the case for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your code is trying to @import _variables.scss and the file name is actually _variable.scss :o)